# How to compute weighted sum of all elements in a row in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, calculated-columns, weighted-average

I have a pandas data frame with multiple columns. I want to create a new column `weighted_sum` from the values in the row and another column vector dataframe `weight`

`weighted_sum` should have the following value:

`row[weighted_sum] = row[col0]*weight[0] + row[col1]*weight[1] + row[col2]*weight[2] + ...`

I found the function `sum(axis=1)`, but it doesn't let me multiply with `weight`.

Edit:
I changed things a bit.

`weight` looks like this:

```
     0
col1 0.5
col2 0.3
col3 0.2
```

`df` looks like this:

```
col1 col2 col3
1.0  2.2  3.5
6.1  0.4  1.2
```

`df*weight` returns a dataframe full of `Nan` values.

Comment: Can you show some of your `DataFrame` and `weights`? It's not clear why you're having a problem doing this. If you just want the dot product of the row values with `weights` then use the `ndarray.dot` method: `row.values.dot(weights.values)`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is that you're multiplying a frame with a frame of a different size with a different row index. Here's the solution:

```
In [121]: df = DataFrame([[1,2.2,3.5],[6.1,0.4,1.2]], columns=list('abc'))

In [122]: weight = DataFrame(Series([0.5, 0.3, 0.2], index=list('abc'), name=0))

In [123]: df
Out[123]:
           a          b          c
0       1.00       2.20       3.50
1       6.10       0.40       1.20

In [124]: weight
Out[124]:
           0
a       0.50
b       0.30
c       0.20

In [125]: df * weight
Out[125]:
           0          a          b          c
0        nan        nan        nan        nan
1        nan        nan        nan        nan
a        nan        nan        nan        nan
b        nan        nan        nan        nan
c        nan        nan        nan        nan
```

You can either access the column:

```
In [126]: df * weight[0]
Out[126]:
           a          b          c
0       0.50       0.66       0.70
1       3.05       0.12       0.24

In [128]: (df * weight[0]).sum(1)
Out[128]:
0         1.86
1         3.41
dtype: float64
```

Or use `dot` to get back another `DataFrame`

```
In [127]: df.dot(weight)
Out[127]:
           0
0       1.86
1       3.41
```

To bring it all together:

```
In [130]: df['weighted_sum'] = df.dot(weight)

In [131]: df
Out[131]:
           a          b          c  weighted_sum
0       1.00       2.20       3.50          1.86
1       6.10       0.40       1.20          3.41
```

Here are the `timeit`s of each method, using a larger `DataFrame`.

```
In [145]: df = DataFrame(randn(10000000, 3), columns=list('abc'))
weight
In [146]: weight = DataFrame(Series([0.5, 0.3, 0.2], index=list('abc'), name=0))

In [147]: timeit df.dot(weight)
10 loops, best of 3: 57.5 ms per loop

In [148]: timeit (df * weight[0]).sum(1)
10 loops, best of 3: 125 ms per loop
```

For a wide `DataFrame`:

```
In [162]: df = DataFrame(randn(10000, 1000))

In [163]: weight = DataFrame(randn(1000, 1))

In [164]: timeit df.dot(weight)
100 loops, best of 3: 5.14 ms per loop

In [165]: timeit (df * weight[0]).sum(1)
10 loops, best of 3: 41.8 ms per loop
```

So, `dot` is faster and more readable.

**NOTE:** If any of your data contain `NaN`s then you should not use `dot` you should use the multiply-and-sum method. `dot` cannot handle `NaN`s since it is just a thin wrapper around `numpy.dot()` (which doesn't handle `NaN`s).

Comment: I was quite astonished by this speed boost, but actually I'm not sure that dot produces the same result. And `df.mul(weight).sum(1)` seems about the same (if a little slower).

Comment: `df.dot(weight)` will produce a `DataFrame` if `df` and `weight` are both `DataFrames`, a `Series` if either is a `Series` and a scalar if both are `Series`. Numerically, they are equivalent.

Comment: The speedup is probably because of the temporary created by the `*` operation. `dot` needs no such temporary :)

Comment: Turns out `dot` does what `numpy` does with `NaN`s: barfs them right back at you.

Comment: `(df * weight).sum(1).head() != df.dot(weight).head()` ?

Comment: Which one of the `weight`s are you using? `Series` or `DataFrame`?

Comment: If `weight` is a `DataFrame` then your above code is correct. If `weight` is a `Series` then it is incorrect. The `weight` the OP provided is a `DataFrame` which is why he was getting all `NaN`s.

Comment: *Obviously* dot is the way to do this (rather than mult followed by sum) :)

Comment: Unless you have `NaN`s which I noted :s

Comment: There's an issue with using `NaN`s in `dot` in specific cases, like covariance matrices not being positive semi-definite if you ignore them. I think R also ran into this issue at some point, but I can't remember what they did. It might have been something like "let the user decide if they want to allow non-`NaN` values into the calculation." I'll create an issue, since I think we should let the user decide, and keep the current behavior as the default.

Answer (score 10):

Assuming weights is a Series of weights for each columns, you can just multiply and do the sum:

```
In [11]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])

In [12]: weights = pd.Series([7, 8, 9], index=['a', 'b', 'c'])

In [13]: (df * weights)
Out[13]: 
    a   b   c
0   7  16  27
1  28  40  54

In [14]: (df * weights).sum(1)
Out[14]: 
0     50
1    122
dtype: int64
```

The benefit of this approach is it takes care of columns which you don't want to weigh:

```
In [21]: weights = pd.Series([7, 8], index=['a', 'b'])

In [22]: (df * weights)
Out[22]: 
    a   b   c
0   7  16 NaN
1  28  40 NaN

In [23]: (df * weights).sum(1)
Out[23]: 
0    23
1    68
dtype: float64
```