# How to sum columns in a dataframe using differentes weights

Tags: python, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
df= 
      product_name     0     1    2
0       laptop       1200  1000  100
1      printer       150    10  100
2       tablet      300    30  560
3         desk      450    40  640
4        chair      200    20  207
```

I want to add the sum of column 1 and 2 but with multiplying the column 1 with 0.7 and 2 by 0.3.

I tried to make the sum for these 2 columns like:

```
df[[1, 2].sum(axis = 1)
```

I can do like that

```
df['Value'] = df.apply(lambda cols: cols[1]*0.7+cols[2]*0.3, axis=1)
```

But I am looking to send the 0.7 and 0.3 as parameter not hard coded.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18420254/18104806) might solve your problem.

Comment: @slowowl it is close, but it supposes to sum all columns. I am looking for some columns

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have `a = 0.7`. You can always do

```
df['Value'] = a * df[1] + (1 - a) * df[2]
```

Alternatively, you can use numpy for many columns. Say you have `weights = [0.5, 0.3, 0.2]` as the weights for the numerical columns, and `index = [0, 1, 2]` to mark which columns correspond to the weights:

```
df[index].to_numpy().dot(weights)
```

Comment: It can be like that but when we have a huge dataframe write the sum like that it willl be a little be hard. I am looking something like what I did in apply.

Comment: @bib. How is this harder than the apply? I'm failing to understand the problem entirely, unless you have many columns involved

Comment: @bib. See additional method

Answer (score 0):

I solved this question finally like that:

```
def weighted_average(data, cols, weights):
    columns = data.columns
    weight = pd.DataFrame(pd.Series(weights, index=columns, name=0))
    weight_index = []
    for name in cols:
        index_no = data.columns.get_loc(name)
        weight_index.append(index_no)
    weight = weight.iloc[weight_index]
    return data[cols].dot(weight)
```